# Getting value of <a> link?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am having troubles pulling the value from a link. It's a CSS formatted page and I would really prefer to use a `<a>` than a `<button>`.

```
<button value="1" onclick="showDetails(this.value)">This works</button>
<a value="2" onclick="showDetails(this.value)">This doesn't work</a>

};
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getdetails.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

How can I get the value of `<a>` when it is clicked and not having it go somewhere?

Comment: `.value` will only grab the element's value if it's a valid property for that element type. `<button>`s have a `value` property, whereas `<a>`s do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only a select few elements, like `<input>`s, `<textarea>`s, and `<button>`s can have `value` properties:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('a').value
);
```

```html
<a value="val">a</a>
```

If you have to use the `value` attribute, use the `getAttribute` method instead of dot notation:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('a').getAttribute('value')
);
```

```html
<a value="val">a</a>
```

Another option would be to use data attributes instead, which would be more appropriate than `value="`s when working with an `<a>`:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('a').dataset.value
);
```

```html
<a data-value="val">a</a>
```

(also make sure to attach your event handlers properly using Javascript if at all possible - inline handlers are generally considered to be pretty poor practice - try using `addEventListener`)

To use `addEventListener`, select your `a`, and call `addEventListener` on it. For example, if your `<a>` has an `id` of `details`:

```js
const details = document.querySelector('#details');
details.addEventListener('click', () => {
  showDetails(details.dataset.value);
});

function showDetails(str) {
  console.log('showing details for ' + str);
}
```

```html
<a id="details" data-value="thevalue">click for details</a>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('a')['value']` should works too

Comment: Dot notation is preferable to bracket notation. Bracket notation should generally only be used if it can't be expressed with dot notation, such as if you're accessing a dynamic property name, or a property name with an illegal character like `-`.

Comment: Who sad it? Preferable by whom? The fastest is the bracket notation with doublequotes.

Comment: @Piterden https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets `Dot notation is faster to write and clearer to read.`

Comment: @Tony See edit, select the element and call `addEventListener` on it

Comment: @CertainPerformance it's only your opinion. It shouldn't be right for everyone. https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js/

Comment: @Piterden It's not just my opinion, that's how it's considered pretty much universally. Even most linters will reject code that uses bracket notation unnecessarily. Why use `['` and `']` when instead of both, you can just use a single `.`? You sometimes see inexperienced coders from languages that use bracket notation use something like `['foo']` instead of `.foo`, but it's not something that should be recommended.

Comment: @Piterden Even your own link looks to prefer dot notation to bracket notation. Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I'm still having trouble trying to get it to work, even with the event handler.

Comment: @Tony Ok, I converted it into a runnable snippet, seems to work just fine

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Thank you so much, but my PHP generates new buttons with new data-values (and unique ids) - what's a way I can handle this?

Comment: Never mine, showDetails(this.dataset.value) seems to work!

Comment: @CertainPerformance my link's general idea is to be consistent. If you started to write with the same way, you should continue with that way till the end of your app development.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a Javascript function to get the value from the link as follows:

```js
function showDetails(a){
  let value = a.getAttribute("value");
  // view value
  console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<!--<button value="1" onclick="showDetails(this)">Button link</button>-->
<a value="2" onclick="showDetails(this)">Anchor link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issues has 2 parts:

**#1: Use of correct attribute**

You should not use the `value` attribute in `<a>` tag, as it's not a valid attribute for HTML standard; try to use `data-val` instead. Attributes starting with `data-` allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks.

Example:

```
<a data-val="2" onclick="showDetails(this)">Test</a>
```

For the JS function, it can be written as:

```
function showDetails(obj) {
    console.log(obj.dataset.val); // 2
}
```

References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

---

**#2: Prevent the `<a>` gets redirected**

The initial choice of using `<a>` is incorrect, as `<a>` is designed to: (1) redirect to other page via hyperlink specified; or (2) go to certain section in the page using anchor name.

However, you can still stop the redirection using JavaScript (though not suggested). Edit your `onclick` function as below:

```
<a data-val="2" onclick="showDetails(this); return false;">Test</a>
```

Note the `return false` is added.

p.s. for better coding standard, you should separate JS from HTML structure.

Answer (score -1):

Anchor tag does not have a value attribute, you can read about it in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes). If you need to assign a value to an anchor tag you can use custom data attribute [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*). In order to get values from `data-*` in your javascript function can try something like this

```
const anchor = document.querySelector('a');
const str = anchor.data.value;
```

And then use it in your ajax logic.

```
const url = 'getdetails.php';
const params = `q=${str}`;
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open('GET', `${url}?${params}`, true);
// ... other logic
```